# How many 5 card hands out of a 52 card deck are there that have at least one red card.

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I am aware of the correct answer, which is:
$$
\text{All possible hands} - \text{All hands with no red cards} = \text{All hands with at least one red card}
$$

However, there is an incorrect argument that I cannot figure out why is wrong. Here is the argument: We first select $26 \choose 1$ red card and then we select $51 \choose 4$ of the remaining cards in the deck. This produces an incorrect result and I do not know why. Intuitively it makes sense to me. Could someone help me out?

Comment: The red card does not have to be the first selected, so multiply by $5$.

Comment: Your method counts each hand with more than one red card as many times as a red card appears in the hand, once for each way you could designate one of the red cards in the hand as the red card in the hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is over-counting.

Consider the case where you end up with A-hearts, 2-hearts, and 3 black cards.  You count this twice, once where the Ace is the (first) red card chosen, and once where the 2 is the first red card chosen.

The actual analysis of what it would take to correct and use such a direct approach is very complicated, since you could have $k$ red cards, where $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}.$

Naturally, the correct enumeration is 
$\binom{52}{5} - \binom{26}{5}.$

Comment: You are correct! Of course! I finally understand now, this had me stumped this whole afternoon. Thank you.